# SOLR: query for multiple fields that are under a same parent tag

Tags: solr

I have multiple documents of users like this

```
<user>
  <id>user1</id>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <role>
    <project>projectA</project>
    <roleName>projectAdmin</roleName>
  </role>
  <role>
    <project>projectB</project>
    <roleName>tester</roleName>
  </role>
</user>
```

How can I construct a query that return users who are projectAdmin of projectB?

This query return user1 which is wrong:

```
"fq": [
    "user.role.project:"projectB",
    "user.role.roleName:projectAdmin"
]
```

I guess as long as there are fields matching the query, there will be results returned. But I also want both values must be under the same role tag. Is there a query syntax for it?